# How to access id of one table in another table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

How I can access the staff who is assigned to this store. when a Store is deleted; I want to change the staff availability flag to true.
currently, I have issue with the staffId!

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int eventId)
  {
        var @store= await _context.Stores.FindAsync(eventId);
       
        _context.Stores.Remove(@store);

        
        //make staff available
        var staff = await _context.Staffs.FindAsync(staffId);
        staff.IsAvailable = true;

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
```

Comment: Please provide the code for all you tables classes (Event, Store, Staff, Staffing, and others?), otherwise it's impossible to help you.

Comment: Thank you Flood, It sorted. Just was missing "ThenInclude":  Include(e => e.StaffingCollection)
              .ThenInclude(s => s.Staff)
              .Where(e => e.StoreId == id)

Answer (score 0):

You don't define `staffId` - *of course* you will have problem with it!

The simplest is to have something like this:

```
var staffs = await _context.Staffs.Where(s => s.storeId == id).Select(s => s).ToListAsync();
foreach(var employee in staffs) {
   employee.IsAvailable = true;
}
```

`Select` is just for clarity; you don't need it

Comment: s.storeId gives error, because Staffs table has no storeId!

Comment: OK. And? does `Stores` and `Staffs` have one-to-many relationship? If *yes*, the `Staffs` have to have id of the Store (in relational database it's called foreign key). What's the name of that column? Use it where I used `storeId`. You have to make a small mental leap in order to help yourself

Comment: I have another table that has many-to-many relationship called Staffing - Staffing has only StaffId and StoreId that connects Store with Staff.

Comment: **First**, it doesn't matter what tables you have. What matters is how you defined the entities in your object model. Tables are build through migrations based on your object model. **Second**, if you have many-to-many relationship between `Staff` and `Store` - then it is a very important part of your question that you totally missed. Assuming you are using .NET 5 or 6, I suggest you start with a tutorial on how to implement many-to-many relationship in Entity Framework. Good luck!

Comment: I think I didn't clear, I have a Store table and Staff table- the store has not got StaffId and Staff has not got SotreId. I have a table called Staffing - it has Two IDs StoreId and StaffId that connects Store with Staff. I am using .Net 3.

Comment: OK, I give up. Maybe you need to use Upwork instead of Stack Overflow